# Traversing with jQuery inside of a table

Tags: jquery, traversal

Here is what I have. Nothing has IDs, Names or Classes.

Could anyone help me figure out how to change the val of the input using Jquery.

I can get to the div, but how do I move from there to the input? Thanks in advance!

$("div:contains(Zipcode)").next(input).val("test1");

```
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td>
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <div>Zipcode</div>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </td>
 <td>
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <input>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5386Lzts/1/

Answer: $("div:contains(Zipcode)").closest("table").next().find("input").val("here it is");

Comment: If this is all your html, then you only have one `input`, so `$("input").val("here it is")`

Comment: `.next()` will only look at siblings, it doesn't go through the rest of the html.  You need to navigate up to go back down, something like:  `$("div:contains(Zipcode)").closest("td").next().find("input").val("here it is");`  this assumes your `td`s are in order.

Comment: there are other inputs after this one and before it

Comment: Why just put an id to the Zipcode ```div``` ??
```<div id="zipcode"></div>
$("#zipcode").next(input).val("test1");```

Comment: If there are other inputs, then any answer here will just be guess work / based only on the code you've provided, so will unlikely work in your real scenario.  You need to provide all the information.

Comment: 2nd one worked.. changed td to table! thank you!

Comment: @cjones try "$(":input").val('test');"

Comment: Just noticed both are in nested tables, so it would be:  `$("div:contains(Zipcode)").closest("table").closest("td").next().find("input").val("here it is");`